# How can I convert an Image selected from my gallery or camera snapshot from my flutter app to base64, display it before I persist to database

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

this has really been giving me a tough time. The Api endpoint receives only binary format. I am able to select the image, encode it to base64 then preview it before persisting to the database but I can't preview it to see what I have selected before I persist it to the post request please can anyone help me?

Here's the code that picks the Image:

```
  Widget bottomSheet() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0), topRight: Radius.circular(16.0)),
      ),
      child: Wrap(
        alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.end,
        children: [
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.camera,
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
            title: Text(
              'Camera',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Get.back();

              takePhoto(ImageSource.camera);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.image,
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
            title: Text(
              'Gallery',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Get.back();
              takePhoto(ImageSource.gallery);

              // profilerController.uploadImage(ImageSource.gallery);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here's the code that converts the image:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

String _imageFile;
Uint8List bytes;
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

void takePhoto(ImageSource source) async {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage( source: source );

    //Encodeding the File
    List<int> imageBytes = await pickedFile.readAsBytes();
    print('Avatar: ${imageBytes}');

    _imageFile =  base64Encode(imageBytes);
    if(mounted) {
      setState(() { 
         bytes = Base64Codec().decode(_imageFile);

      });


    }
  }
```

Here's the code that displays the Image

```
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image(
                          image: _imageFile == null
                              ? AssetImage("assets/images/user2.png")
                              : Image.memory(bytes)

                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          bottom: 1,
                          right: 1,
                          child: Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            child: InkWell(
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.add_a_photo,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                {
                                  showModalBottomSheet(
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: ((builder) => bottomSheet()),
                                  );
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.orange[500],
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

After selecting I kept on getting:

```
Another exception was thrown: type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'ImageProvider<Object>'[1]][1]
```

Any Help or suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thank you

UI of the app
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the ImageProvider of the Image as:

```
     Image(
                          image: _imageFile == null
                              ? AssetImage("assets/images/user2.png")
                              : Image.memory(bytes).image

                        ),
```